# Proof that shortest path with negative cycles is NP hard

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

I'm looking into the shortest path problem and am wondering how to prove that shortest path with neg. cycles is NP-hard. (Or is it NPC? Is there a way to validate in P time that the path really is shortest?)

How would I reduce the SAT problem into the shortest path problem in polynomial time?

Comment: Do you have to reduce from SAT? A simple reduction is from Hamiltonian path.

Comment: The decision version of your problem is: Given a graph and a number $\ell$, is there a path whose length is shorter than $\ell$? This is clearly in NP.

Answer (score 5):

Copied from my answer on [cstheory.stackexchange.com](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/17463/8532):

---

Paths with no repeated vertices are called [simple-paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28graph_theory%29#Different_types_of_paths), so you are looking for the shortest simple-path in a graph with negative-cycles.

This can be reduced from the [longest-path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).  If there were a fast solver for your problem, then given a graph with only positive edge-weights, negating all the edge-weights and running your solver would give the longest path in the original graph.

Thus your problem is NP-Hard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While I was looking for a conversion from SAT (as, based on Cook's theorem, it's what I know to be NPC), connecting the dots led me to "Hamiltonian path to longest path" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#NP-hardness and then "3SAT to Hamiltonian path" https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/proof-hamiltonian-path-np-complete/